Error de sintaxis inválida Python al intentar ejecutar script
Estoy empezando a programar, cuando intento ejecutar un programa sencillo con un loop ya sea for ó while, como este
from random import randint
vidas = 8
random = randint(1, 100)
while vidas > 8:
    vidas -= 1

En la terminal me muestra el siguiente error
>>> & C:/Users/Braian/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/Braian/Desktop/Python/inversa.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/Braian/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe c:/Users/Braian/Desktop/Python/inversa.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


Suena similar a esta pregunta.

El hecho de que en el error muestras el prompt >>> me hace pensar que estás en el shell interactivo dentro del intérprete de Python, que no es lo mismo que el shell del sistema (cmd.exe o powershell.exe).
El shell interactivo de python pasa los comandos que escribas directamente al intérprete para su ejecución. Es decir, en este shell, lo que escribes es directamente código python.
Por ejemplo, recién inicié el shell e hice este ejemplo en mi PC:
Python 3.12.3 (tags/v3.12.3:f6650f9, Apr  9 2024, 14:05:25) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print("hola mundo!")
hola mundo!
>>>

No es lo más habitual iniciar scripts desde este shell, pero si aún quieres iniciarlo desde allí, puedes usar la función exec() junto a la función open() para iniciar el script desde este shell interactivo de Pyhton, así:
>>>exec(open("c:/Users/Braian/Desktop/Python/inversa.py").read())

Sin embargo, como he dicho antes, lo más común es ejecutarlo directamente desde la línea de comandos del sistema, ya sea cmd.exe o powershell.exe, invocando al intérprete y pasando como parámetro el nombre del archivo del script, de manera similar a como lo estabas haciendo tú dentro del shell interactivo de python:
C:\>C:\Users\Braian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe c:/Users/Braian/Desktop/Python/inversa.py

Nota como he dejado la diagonal inversa como separador de carpetas en la primera parte, pues este shell no soporta el uso de diagonales para separarlas.
OJO: He dejado los prompts y otros textos de la salida en los ejemplos para dar claridad, pero lo que se escribe en la línea de comandos es solo lo que está después del >

Bien visto.. Aclarale que ademas su programa no hace absolutamente nada....

@gbianchi, considero que su duda es sobre como ejecutar el script, y creo que lo útil para las generaciones por venir con el mismo problema sería encontrar la información de como ejecutarlo en la respuesta. Ya, sobre si el script hace o no lo que pretende, sería una nueva pregunta y una respuesta distinta.

si no lo haces.. en 5 minutos viene con la pregunta de mi programa no hace nada :/

Y eso sería lo correcto. Generalmente no respondo pensando en la persona que realizó la pregunta. Mi objetivo al responder es construir una base de conocimiento en español sobre problemas de programación. Si viene con una nueva pregunta, por mi, enhorabuena, probablemente no sea yo quien la responda. El formato del sitio es: una pregunta por publicación, si preguntara aquí sobre lo que hace o no hace el script yo hubiese votado por cerrar esta pregunta.

@gbianchi dejalo que haga una pregunta por cada cosa que no entienda o no le funcione ... si ya existe se marca como duplicado  y si no que alguien le responda ... si mete 2 o 3 o 4 preguntas en un solo post tambien te quejas diciendo que no esta enfocado y quiere cerrar las preguntas  ...
